# What is the Big O run time of these codes?

Tags: python, algorithm

```
test = 0
for i in range(n):          
   for j in range(n):
       test = test + i * j
```

***********B*********

```
test = 0
for i in range(n):          
   test = test + 1
```

***********C*********

```
for j in range(n):
    test = test – 1         
i = n               
while i > 0:
   k = 2 + 2
   i = i // 2
```

For A, I believe it is O(N^2) because of the nested for loop, for B it is O(N) since it is a single for loop. And for C, I guess it is O(n * log(n)) since it is a for loop and while loop. Am I correct in assuming this?

Comment: I too agree for first two, but why would `C` be `n*log(n)` since it is two different loops, for loop is O(n) which dominates while loop so, wouldn't it be O(n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had it right up until the last one, since the loops are not nested it would be `O(n + log(n))` and since `n > log(n)` it would simply be `O(n)`

Comment: Thanks for the input! but why do we omit the log(n) part? I'm having trouble wrapping my head around that. What does n > log(n) prove

Comment: @Acoolguy when we are interested in time complexity of a function really what we care about are how they will behave for a very large number of inputs. As n tends towards larger and larger numbers `n` becomes much much larger than `log(n)` (you can verify this with a graph). Essentially the fact that there is a loop with `O(log(n))` doesn't really mean much for large inputs of n

Comment: Take n = 500000000 then, log(n) is close to 28 which is very less, so we consider only n since, it shows n is more dominating and log(n) is much smaller value.

Comment: @Acoolguy : You can find various excercises like `n+logn = n`. It's what we derive from Big-O definition. For e.g. you can have look on http://slideplayer.com/slide/3195484/11/images/12/Big-O+Notation+if+there+exist+positive+constants+c+and+n0+such+that.jpg